# вывести из блока в модальное окно

Tags: jquery, ajax

аяксом из БД выводятся данные

стандартное модальное окно из bootstrap

```
<div class="modal fade" id="basicModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="basicModal" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Basic Modal</h4>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <h3>Modal Body</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

аякс скрипт

```
 success: function (response) {
                        var  tr_str='';
                        var len = response.length;
                        for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                            var id = response[i].id;
                            var title = response[i].title;
                            var price = response[i].price;
                             tr_str +=
                                "<div class='goods-card' data-new='" + id + "' data-price='" + price + "' data-Alfavit='" + title + "'>" +
                                "<h1>" + title + "</h1>" +
                                "<p>" + price + "</p>"+
                                 "<div class='col text-center'>"+
                                 "<a href='#' class='btn btn-lg btn-success' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#basicModal'>Купить</a>"+
                                     "</div>";
                            tr_str +=  "</div>";
                        }
                        $(".goods-wrap").html(tr_str);
                    }
                });
```

по нажатию на эту ссылку                              `"<a href='#' class='btn btn-lg btn-success' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#basicModal'>Купить</a>"+`
открывается модальное окно,  как из конкретного блока по нажатию на ссылку  загрузить данные?

Comment: Что значит "...из конкретного блока..."? Что откуда вам надо загрузить?

Comment: @InDevX, то и значит, оно же массивом выводится, значит блок не один

Comment: @аноним хочется вам помочь и есть возможности, но вопрос ваш далеко не очевиден. Если это аякс, то логично по саксесу сразу показывать модальное окно с данными. Но вы пишите про нажати на <a>, у которго есть атрибут data-target, который сам по себе вызывает целевое модальное окно. Далее вы пишите про конкретный блок, есть догадка что блок в который подставились данные, возвращаемые аяксом. Один он на странице - не понятно. Как блок связан со ссылкой - не понятно. Либо переосмыслите вопрос, либо покажите что и как делаете, может так что-то прояснится.

Comment: @аноним кажется, я вас понял. Что именно нужно передать?

Comment: @InDevX, все содержимое блока <div class='goods-card' > кроме ссылки <a href='#' class='btn btn-lg btn-success'>

Comment: @аноним Ответил. То что надо?

Comment: @InDevX, да именно то

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Насколько я вас понял, настолько и дам ответ. 
У вас данные выводятся посредством ajax. В виде блоков

```
<div class='goods-card' data-new='1' data-price='111' data-Alfavit='Заголовок'>
    <h1>Заголовок</h1>
    <p>111</p>
    <div class='col text-center'>
        <a href='#' class='btn btn-lg btn-success buy' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#basicModal'>Купить</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

При нажатии на кнопку `Купить` вы ходите передавать данные. Осуществлять это можно несколькими способами. Самый простой - давать временный атрибут блоку по нажатии на ссылку.

```
$(document).on('click','a.buy',()=>{ $(this).closest('div.goods-card').addClass('current'); });
```

Теперь, при нажатии на ссылку будет добавляться класс `current` блоку, на котором нажата ссылка, и в открывшемся модальном окне вы можете брать любые данные через этот клас. Например, data атрибуты блока:

```
let id = $('div.current').data('new');  //получаем data-new
let price = $('div.current').data('price'); //получаем data-prive
let title = $('div.current').data('Alfavit'); //получаем data-Alfavit
```

***ВАЖНО!***

Поскольку мы при нажатии добавляли класс текущему блоку, то его надо и убирать. Лучшим вариантом будет убирать его по закрытии модалки. Bootstrap для этих целей имеет события. Например, `hide.bs.modal` - событие срабатывает перед закрытием окна.

```
$('#basicModal').on('hide.bs.modal',()=>{ $('div.goods-card').removeClass('current'); });
```